# Prove that if $g ∈ Ω(1)$, then $a + g ∈ Θ(g)$

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

Prove that for all functions $f,g : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R^{≥0}}$, and all numbers $a ∈ \mathbb{R^{≥0}}$, if $g ∈ Ω(1)$, then $a + g ∈ Θ(g)$.

Comment: What is $\Omega(1)$ and $\Theta(g)$ ?????

Comment: @JeanMarie I have expanded on these below.

Comment: Very well. But as @Arjuba commented, it should have been merged with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the definitions, this is what I have done so far:

Let $f,g : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R^{≥0}}$, and let $a ∈ \mathbb{R^{≥0}}$. Assume that $g ∈ Ω(g)$, i.e., that there exist $c_0, n_0 ∈ \mathbb{R^+}$ such that for all $n ∈ N$, if $n ≥ n_0$ then $g(n) ≥ c_0$. We want to prove that $a+g ∈ Θ(g)$, i.e., that there exist $c_1, c_2, n_1 ∈ \mathbb{R^+}$ such that for all $n ∈ N$, if $n ≥ n1$ then $c_1 g(n) ≤ a + g(n) ≤ c_2g(n)$.

I can't seem to be able to work out what $c_1$ and $c_2$ should be equal to. I can see that $n_2=n_1$ though. If anyone can expand on this, that'd be great.

Comment: You should put that under you question.